# Using iteration to create a number square

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, iteration

I was creating a basic number square grid using iteration (only using FOR loops). Unfortunately, I faced some issues with the program not presenting the number square in the preferred format I was trying to present it in - 1 to 10 above and on the side of the number square.

Without using arrays and only FOR loops, could someone help me find a method to present the number square in my preferred format:

```
Console.WriteLine("[] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10")
Console.WriteLine("1  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("2  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("3  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("4  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("5  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("6  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("7  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("8  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("9  / / / / / / / / / /")
Console.WriteLine("5  / / / / / / / / / /")




Sub Main()
    Dim output As Integer

    For count1 = 0 To 10
        Console.Write(Format(output, " 000") & " ")
    Next
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()

    For count3 = 1 To 10
        For count4 = 0 To 10
            output = count3 * count4
            Console.Write(Format(output, " 000") & " ")
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

Comment: Console.Write(" {0} ", Format(count1, "000"))

Comment: jdweng, what does this bracket do: {}

Comment: It is the index number of a parameter.  So parameter zero is the format statement.